# Is this the correct method to transform two 2D points to one 3D?

Tags: transform, camera-calibration

There's a moving object whose imagePoints I identity at two times with two MS LifeCams on my Windows 7 PC in MSVSC++.  I want to determine the distance between those two 3D points.  The steps I'm using are shown.  I included almost no detail since now I want to just learn if I'm using the right OCV 2.3.1 functions.

)1. calibrateCamera for each camera

output: cameraMatrix and distCoeffs for each camera

)2. simpleBlobDetect once for each camera at two times

```
 output: point 1 (cam1x1, cam1y1) (cam2x1, cam2y1)

 output: point 2 (cam1x2, cam1y2) (cam2x2, cam2y2)
```

)3. stereoCalibrate

```
 output: R, T, E, & F
```

)4. stereoRectify

```
this doesn't actually rectify any images but produces R1,R2,P1 & P2 so it can be done
```

)5. undistortPoints

```
output: vector of Point2f objects in rectified image
```

)6. perspectiveTransform

```
 output: vector of Point3f objects
```

From 30k feet are these the correct steps?

Thanks.
Charles